# correct convention of assigning values to enum elements

Tags: c

```
gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu2) 4.6.1
c89
```

What is the correct convention of assigning values to enum elements, so there is no conflict with other enum types?

I have often seen hex format and I am using wondering is there any reason for this?

In my source code I have more than one enum type, so I have done the following:

```
typedef enum transfer_states_e {
    /* Call transfer bind/supervised */
    STATE_TRANSFER_IDLE     = 0x1,

    STATE_INIT_BLIND        = 0x2,
    STATE_INIT_SUPERVISED   = 0x3,

    STATE_INVOKE_BLIND      = 0x4,
    STATE_INVOKE_SUPERVISED = 0x5
} transfer_states_e;

typedef enum states_e {
    /* Initial state */
    STATE_IDLE = 0x6,
    STATE_NULL = 0x7,
    .
    .
    .
} states_e;
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need to have enum values be unique across your project, unless a single address or variable might contain a value belonging to more than one enum. This is fairly unlikely, but it might be a sanity measure.

Enum values might be encoded in hex format for ease of debugging on projects that do network communication, as applications like Wireshark tend to show hexadecimal output. More likely, it is just the programmer's personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the values to be unique, they should belong to a single enumeration.  Separate enumerations can have overlapping sets of values without causing any problems to the normal C program.

If you really have a a good reason for needing disjoint sets of values across enumerations, then I guess you should define a conventional 'last member' of each enumeration, and use that to start the next one:

```
typedef enum transfer_states_e {
    /* Call transfer bind/supervised */
    STATE_TRANSFER_IDLE = 1,
    STATE_INIT_BLIND,
    STATE_INIT_SUPERVISED,
    STATE_INVOKE_BLIND,
    STATE_INVOKE_SUPERVISED,
    STATE_TRANSFER_LAST = STATE_INVOKE_SUPERVISED
} transfer_states_e;

typedef enum states_e {
    /* Initial state */
    STATE_IDLE = STATE_TRANSFER_LAST + 1,
    STATE_NULL,
    .
    .
    .
    STATE_LAST = ...
} states_e;
```

Anything else is not going to work well when you need a new (transfer) state.  Of course, that will immediately change all previous values.  And if you claim your software will never change, I've got a bridge in Brooklyn to sell you.